# SQL statement to replace TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE Table Person (PersonID int)
INSERT INTO Person (1)
INSERT INTO Person (2)
INSERT INTO Person (3)
INSERT INTO Person (4)
INSERT INTO Person (5)

CREATE TABLE PersonCrime (PersonID in,CrimeID int)
INSERT INTO PersonCrime (1,1)
INSERT INTO PersonCrime (2,1)
INSERT INTO PersonCrime (3,2)
INSERT INTO PersonCrime (9,3)
INSERT INTO PersonCrime (4,3)
```

I want to return all the crimes from PersonCrime where all the persons are in the person table.  For example, crime 1 is returned because persons 1 and 2 are in the person table.  Crime 2 is also returned because person 3 is in the person table.  Crime 3 is not returned because person 9 is not in the person table even though person 4 is.

I have done this using TSQL i.e. looping around all the crimes and checking all persons.  However, this takes far to long. I am trying to do it with SQL.

Comment: @Hart Co, when I say TSQL; I meant procedural SQL.  I tried this but it takes far too long.

Comment: T-Sql certainly is not Microsoft's implementation of Sql.  The OP's distinction is quite accurate.

Comment: @w0051977, if you can provide a little more information here you could probably get more highly optimized queries.  How large is your dataset?  Would it be better to optimize for ignoring or keeping entries?

Comment: @HughJones Perhaps I've misunderstood the terminology all this time, if you write queries in SQL Server, are you not using TSQL?

Comment: @Hart Co, I think what Hugh Jones is saying is that TSQL is a Microsoft EXTENSION of SQL as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL.  It allows you to add procedural logic.  Therefore there is a difference between SQL and TSQL as implied in the question.

Comment: That makes sense, but I've never heard someone phrase a question in that way "convert TSQL to SQL", I thought of TSQL as inclusive, SQL + procedural extension of SQL.   Luckily for me, the distinction doesn't seem too important.  Hope one of the answers below is helpful.

Comment: @Hart - I was perhaps being a little pedantic, but T-Sql started life as the programming language for Sybase and, as others have said, is a procedural language.  SQL is a query language (only) and is a standard supported by all relational databases (I would say it is part of the definitional of what a relational database is).  Having said that, T-Sql supports, or perhaps includes, an implementation of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

With a table variable for clarity:

```
DECLARE @IgnoreCrime TABLE (CrimeID int);

INSERT INTO @IgnoreCrime SELECT CrimeID FROM PersonCrime WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID FROM Person)
SELECT DISTINCT(CrimeID) FROM PersonCrime WHERE CrimeID NOT IN (SELECT CrimeID FROM @IgnoreCrime)
```

without:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CrimeID) 
FROM #PersonCrime 
WHERE CrimeID NOT IN 
  (SELECT CrimeID 
   FROM #PersonCrime 
   WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID FROM #Person))
```

Comment: This will return crime 3 even though person 9 is not in the Person table.

Comment: I was a little too quick on the trigger with posting - I'm refactoring it, will update in a minute

Comment: the poster wants to return the crimes, not store them.  There is absolutely no benefit in creating a table

Comment: I provided another example without the table variable - but a table variable might provide a little more clarity about what's going on when he returns to this later and wonders what the heck is going on.

Comment: Also, if the poster has a very lage dataset or needs to do some data reorganization to enhance performance, table variables (and then probablyt emp tables) would be a step in that direction

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT CrimeID
FROM PersonCrime PC
LEFT JOIN Person P
  ON PC.PersonID = P.PersonID
GROUP BY CrimeID
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN P.PersonID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) <> 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42d72/3/0)

Answer (score 1):

Defined another way - "give me all `CrimeID`s where there is not a `PersoinID` that is not in the `Person` table":

```
SELECT DISTINCT CrimeID 
FROM PersonCrime pc
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM PersonCrime
    WHERE CrimeID = pc.CrimeID 
        AND PersonID NOT IN (SELECT PersonID FROM PERSON)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exists` Operator to find the `personID` present in `Person` try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CrimeID
FROM   PersonCrime PC
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Person P
               WHERE  p.PersonID = pc.PersonID)
GROUP  BY CrimeID
HAVING Count(CrimeID) = (SELECT Count(1)
                         FROM   PersonCrime PC1
                         WHERE  PC.CrimeID = PC1.CrimeID)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1889/1)

Comment: Please comment the reason of downvoting so that i can improve my answer

Comment: Doubt you'll get one, as I didn't either.

Comment: Indeed!  A little less identical in answer this time though, I like mine a little better, but I certainly wouldn't downvote a correct answer.

Comment: @HartCO -yeah, Clearly your's is a better one :)

Comment: My guess would be that with the HAVING clause it runs slowly on a large dataset.  I upvoted though, it works.